# Getting first image from content in silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have the following method where it is suppose to get the first image that is displayed from the content.

```
public function FirstImage($content)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content);

    Debug::dump($content);

}
```

The wierd thing is when i do **$dom->loadHTML** I get the following error `Empty string supplied as input`, but as soon as I dump it I do get the correct data. How can I fix this problem ?

I also done $this->owner->Content which has the same thing.

Comment: more context of your code is required. where do you call FirstImage()?

Comment: Do you get the dump from the same call of your method? Did you abort right after it (aka. `die();`)? Did you check with a good debugger like xdebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the late response wasn't on my computer during the weekend, I have found a better solution then using the DOMDocument instance by using the preg_match_all. Here is the following code that I have used.

```
    $pattern = '/<img[^>]+src[\\s=\'"]';
    $pattern .= '+([^"\'>\\s]+)/is';

    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $match)) {
        $imageLink = preg_replace('/_resampled\/resizedimage[0-9]*-/', '', $match[1][0]);

        return (string) $imageLink;
    }
```